# Docker init Daemon best practices (PID 1 zombie reaping)

Tags: linux, docker, init, alpine-linux

yesterday i read more about the topic of the pid 1 zombie reaping and how it can cause problems in docker: https://blog.phusion.nl/2015/01/20/docker-and-the-pid-1-zombie-reaping-problem/ .

i use alpine linux for most of my containers and be curious what are currently the best practices to solve this or if docker itself can manage this in some way already.

some links from my research so far maybe useful for others:

- [dumb-init](https://github.com/Yelp/dumb-init)
- [tini](https://github.com/krallin/tini)
- [s6](https://github.com/skarnet/s6)

that said i also read the alpine linux comes with [openrc](https://github.com/OpenRC/openrc).

would love to hear about the current situation and share experience.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `runit` which is lightweight. Here is an Alpine Docker image with runit: https://github.com/nimmis/docker-alpine-micro

https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker/issues/275 talks about Alpine:3.5 having runit. I checked the latest image and it does not.

It should also be pretty straightforward to implement `s6` with alpine.